# Content Delivery trigger not firing

Tags: trigger, content

I'm attempting to create a trigger on content delivery (ContentDistribution).  However, my trigger isn't being fired when ContentDistribution records are created in an Apex controller for a VisualForce page.  If they are created from the UI/UX or from execute anonymous, the trigger runs fine.

Apex creation:

```
ContentDistribution distribution = new ContentDistribution();
distribution.Name = newVersion.Title__c + '-' + Date.today();
distribution.ContentVersionId = newVersion.Id;
distribution.PreferencesNotifyOnVisit = false;
distribution.PreferencesNotifyRndtnComplete = false;

try {
    insert distribution;
}
catch (DmlException ex) {

}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger ContentDistributionTrigger on ContentDistribution (after insert) {
    system.debug('~~~~~ in trigger');
}
```

Debug log from Apex insert (notice no trigger call!):

```
16:33:54.0 (164541755)|DML_BEGIN|[119]|Op:Insert|Type:ContentDistribution|Rows:1
16:33:54.0 (164568849)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
16:33:54.0 (207713301)|DML_END|[119]
```

Debug log from UI:

```
16:30:48.0 (286152)|EXECUTION_STARTED
16:30:48.0 (312575)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|VisualForce View State
16:30:48.0 (8178812)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|VisualForce View State
16:30:48.0 (9061246)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
16:30:48.109 (109687142)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qXXXXXXXXXXXX|TestTrigger on ContentDistribution trigger event AfterInsert for [05DXXXXXXXXXXXX]
```

VF code:

```
<apex:page controller="XXXXX" showHeader="true" sidebar="false">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="File" for="file" />
                <apex:inputFile value="{!VersionData}" fileName="{!PathOnClient}" id="file"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!upload}" value="Upload New Version" />
        <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Controller code:

```
public without sharing class XXXXX {

public Blob VersionData {get; set;}
public String PathOnClient {get; set;}

private ContentVersion newVersion;
private String versionId;
private String objectId;
private ContentVersion currentContent;
private List<ContentVersion> objectContent;

public XXXXX() {
    this.versionId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    this.objectId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('objId');

    this.newVersion = new ContentVersion();

    this.currentContent = getCurrentContent(this.versionId);
    this.objectContent = getObjectContent(this.objectId);
}

public PageReference upload() {

    if (!doesFileMatch()) {
        this.VersionData = null;
        return null;
    }

    for (ContentVersion content : this.objectContent) {
        if (content.PathOnClient == currentContent.PathOnClient) {
            this.newVersion.Title = content.Title;
            this.newVersion.TagCsv = content.TagCsv;
            this.newVersion.Title__c = content.Title__c;
            this.newVersion.Document_Type__c = content.Document_Type__c;
            this.newVersion.Document_Purpose__c = content.Document_Purpose__c;
            this.newVersion.ContentDocumentId = content.ContentDocumentId;
            this.newVersion.VersionData = this.VersionData;
            this.newVersion.PathOnClient = this.PathOnClient;
            this.newVersion.Display_On_List__c = true;
        }
    }

    this.VersionData = null;

    try {
        insert this.newVersion;
    }
    catch (DmlException ex) {
        return null;
    }

    createContentDelivery();
    return null;
}

private ContentVersion getCurrentContent(String versionId) {
    return [SELECT Id, PathOnClient, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :versionId];
}

private List<ContentVersion> getObjectContent(String objectId) {
    List<ContentVersion> objectContent = new List<ContentVersion>();
    List<Id> objectContentIds = new List<Id>();
    List<ContentDistribution> deliveredContent = [SELECT ContentVersionId FROM ContentDistribution WHERE RelatedRecordId = :objectId];

    for (ContentDistribution content : deliveredContent) {
        objectContentIds.add(content.ContentVersionId);
    }

    if (!objectContentIds.isEmpty()) {
        objectContent = [SELECT Id, Title, TagCsv, ContentDocumentId, PathOnClient, Title__c, Document_Type__c, Document_Purpose__c FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id IN :objectContentIds];
    }

    return objectContent;
}

private Boolean doesFileMatch() {
    if (this.PathOnClient == this.currentContent.PathOnClient) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public void createContentDelivery() {
    ContentDistribution distribution = new ContentDistribution();
    distribution.Name = newVersion.Title__c + '-' + Date.today();
    distribution.ContentVersionId = newVersion.Id;
    //distribution.RelatedRecordId = this.objectId;
    distribution.PreferencesNotifyOnVisit = false;
    distribution.PreferencesNotifyRndtnComplete = false;

    try {
        insert distribution;
    }
    catch (DmlException ex) {
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How are you creating those records through Apex? Kindly share relevant portion of your apex code.

Comment: I've added the relevant code.

Comment: Is ContentDistribution record created successfully using above APEX call? Also check if your trigger is "active".

Comment: Trigger is active and content delivery is created successfully.  It works when creating a content delivery via the UI just fine.

Comment: I've added the relevant debug log outputs as well.  I'm about 99% sure this is a Salesforce bug.

Comment: What is your API version of the trigger and can you confirm?

Comment: API version is 38.  Tried 34 and 37 too with no luck.

Comment: Try adding other events such as, delete or update may be and trigger them from your apex code like you did with INSERT case and see if they get fired.

Comment: Append your exception message (if any) to your debug log. Are their any required fields for creation of ContentDistribution records? System.debug('message=' + ex.getMessage());

Comment: @Mahmood, I did already and they didn't.

Comment: @TSmith, no exception is thrown and the records are created successfully in Apex, but don't fire the trigger.

Comment: Im able to get into the trigger without any prob.
`trigger ContentDistributionTrg on ContentDistribution (before insert, after insert) {
 String BeforeOrAfter = (Trigger.isBefore ? 'Before' : 'After');
 String TriggerType = ''
 + (Trigger.isInsert ? 'Insert' : '');
system.debug(BeforeOrAfter + ' ' + TriggerType );
}`

Answer (score 0):

> **There are no bugs in Salesforce.**

I have used this code to run from Developer console and trigger on `ContentDistribution` is perfectly firing.

First, created a ContentVersion and followed by ContentDistribution (same as your code)

```
ContentVersion newVersion = new ContentVersion();
newVersion.Title = 'my version title';
newVersion.pathOnClient = 'C:/Santanu/Plan.txt';
newVersion.VersionData=blob.valueof('test data');
insert newVersion;

ContentDistribution distribution = new ContentDistribution();
distribution.Name = newVersion.title + ' ' +  Date.today();
distribution.ContentVersionId = newVersion.Id;
distribution.PreferencesNotifyOnVisit = false;
distribution.PreferencesNotifyRndtnComplete = false;

try {
    insert distribution;
}
catch (DmlException ex) {

}
```

> **Update** based on your code

I have checked that trigger is firing properly.

In the `upload` method, certain condition is not satisfying. Thats why you are unable to get the trigger log.

Suggest you to put debug statements in these lines:

1. before and after this line `if (!doesFileMatch())`
2. Inside the for loop after this line  `if (content.PathOnClient == currentContent.PathOnClient)`
3. Before and after `insert this.newVersion;` line
4. Inside `createContentDelivery` method.

Comment: This does not resolve my issue.  The trigger is still not firing from a controller on a VisualForce page.

Comment: Can you please post VFP and controller code

Comment: Posted.  I've tried to move the creation to both a future method and a batch for testing, and none of them fired the trigger.  So far I've only been able to successfully fire the trigger from the UI or execute anonymous.

Comment: find my updated answer

Comment: Your answer still does not resolve my issue.  Find the debug logs in the original post.  From the controller, the ContentDistribution is being inserted but the trigger is never firing.

I know what my code is doing.  It is all running, but the trigger is never being fired from the Apex controller.  I've also tried moving my createContentDelivery method to @future and passing in the ContentVersion id, but that also did not fire the trigger.  Same with moving to a batch in a wild attempt at closure on this issue.  Nothing has fired the trigger except the UI and execute anon for me.

Comment: can you put debug log level to finest and check if it is showing

Comment: It is not showing.  See the debug log already attached.

Comment: Then raise a case to Salesforce